# Unable to get Parallax from SwiperJS working on my website

Tags: parallax, swiper.js

I followed the documentation for setting up from CDN but does not seem to be working.

See https://github.com/dancarlton/FannyBreakers for reference to code

Tried to get the parallax scroll and it is not working. Making a product website for a client to showcase their products and they liked the look of the parallax. But for some reason I cant get it working

Comment: Provided GitHub link is not available.

Comment: apologies, forgot to make the repo public